# Parsing image into data [any language]

Tags: php, c++, asp.net, image, image-processing

I am trying to provide an image to a programming language and return a set of data specific to that type of image. The image size may change and location of certain elements may change. However, all elements will be in the same location relative to a specific object.

I will need to extract text and numbers from the image.

This can be done in really any language. I am most confident in my PHP/C++ programming abilities, but I can make anything work. I would probably prefer a Windows app over PHP just for usability.

As far as I know, this should be possible, if complicated. If someone can point me in the right direction I can work from there. A search here and on Google returns nothing more than people trying to parse image links from JSON/XML and such.

Thanks in advance! Comment if you would like any more info

**Edit:** To be more specific, this is for a friend to help him automate the more tedious parts of leading his Guilds. The images below are two separate games that I would like to be able to use this for. The fields I need to extract are selected. Keep in mind the size of the image may change (they are just screenshots and could be any size)

[image removed]

I will need to extract the image and the corresponding number. The image will need to be matched with a set of images to determine a "name" that the number will go with. Every item on that screen needs to be extracted.

[image removed]

In this game I need to extract the name and both the donation amounts which correspond to that user handle. I will need to do it for every username on that page.

Comment: Can you provide a sample image to give us an idea of the difficulties you are facing? You say "...this should be possible, if complicated." but have you tried existing OCR projects such as the ones Kleist suggests?

Comment: after so many years the best ocr program out there [ABBYY FineReader](http://finereader.abbyy.com/) is doing pretty much squat to my user made captchas.

Comment: @madflow I'm not I promise! I'm looking to automate the retrieval and storage of data that (from what I can tell) can only be "seen" (by me and manually recorded or a screenshot and automatically recorded, my goal!)

Comment: @Tony I will provide sample images in just a moment.

Comment: @vlzvl I need to process the data and store it in a database. Can ABBYY FineReader do that?

Comment: Take a look at http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fhabrahabr.ru%2Fpost%2F126739%2F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting text from images is called Optical Character Recognition aka OCR. Since you're mentioning C++ I'd suggest you start with [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).

This looks like a good starting point: [Basic OCR in OpenCV](http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/)

When it comes to extracting images. In that case what you want to start with is probably edge-detection.

[OpenCV tutorial including edge-detection](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut5.html)

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at that now. :)

Comment: I posted images. Can you take a look and offer your insight? OpenCV seems extremely complicated for even a single-channel image. This might not be possible.

Comment: Well, OpenCV is complicated but also extremely powerful, and your task is not that simple after all, so I think it's a good match. I don't know of any other libraries, but there might exist some which can do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for sharing OpenCV. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used OCR in PHP, but I came across this article that MIGHT help you out.

http://de77.com/php/ocr-optical-character-recognition-in-php

It utilizes the OCR library located here:

http://jocr.sourceforge.net/download.html